# autoPlay param not workingin flash player

Tags: flash, video, parameters, video-player

I have an embedded Flash movie player. Currently it starts playing when the page loads and I do not want this to occur. I have added:

```
<param name="autoStart" value="false" />
```

But it doesn't make any difference, nor does:

```
<param name="autoStart" value="0" />
```

Does anyone know of another way to stop this auto occurring?

The video is [here](http://libbymunro.com/index.php?id=12), and my full code if needed:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="650" height="405" bgcolor="#000000" data="movies/movie01.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="autoStart" value="false" />
<param name="BGCOLOR" value="#000000" />
<param name="menu" value="true" />
<param name="src" value="movies/movie01.swf" />
<param name="pluginspage" value="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manualy stop the video once it's loaded or add a `stop()` call to the swf file.
It's simple but will do the work.